# Non-zero voltage measured across shorted positive and negative differential probes tied to a single circuit node

Tags: noise, voltage-measurement, probe

If I place the positive and negative probe tips of a differential probe on the same location, and therefore the same node, (such as sharing a test point), I would expect to read a zero voltage.

What phenomena causes me to read voltage differentials when the probes are touching each other (and therefore shorted) as well as a node?

The probes are fine prior to system enable: offset has been zeroed out. The wires are tightly twisted and the grabber triggers are ziptied together, leaving only the final length of grabber tips untwisted.

Common mode noise has been suggested; however, I don't understand the phenomena that noise could be read on shorted tips. How does it appear?

Comment: Where are the probe grounds connected?

Comment: Differential probe. No ground, just a + and a -. Ground exists on the oscilloscope, by residential outlet ground connection. Unit under test has grounded chassis by industrial mains ground connection.

Comment: What waveform? Or is this a DC error? Is CM range being exceeded?

Answer (score 3):

> *What phenomena causes me to read voltage differentials when the probes
> are touching each other (and therefore shorted) as well as a node?*

1. Input offset voltage error (always present)
2. Common mode rejection errors (varies with the node's common mode voltage)

Comment: Updated above. : j (How can unrejected common mode be read on shorted tips?)

Comment: @kando the whole business of common mode errors (not noise <-- I didn't say noise) is dependent on the circuit used inside the differential probes and, I suggest you read up on it rather than extend your question to cover it. Reason: it takes us to a different form of answer and an analysis of your probes specific circuit of which I am hesitant to do within the confines of this answer. It is my opinion that you should roll back your question edits and, research it a bit more then, come back with a brand new question should you need clarification.

Comment: @kando are we done here now?

Answer (score 3):

3. Voltage pickup via the probe wiring, especially if the wires are not a tight pair as in a twisted-pair or coax arrangement.

Comment: Updated above. : j